# Program "sometimes" crash when using free

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

My program sometimes crash, and sometimes not when im calling free() on a element from my array. The elements in the array are a struct. I'll show with some code:

```
//This first part might be a bit messy, and hard to understand but it is working
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      komplexNumber komplexNumbers[antal-1]; 
      int i;

      float temp;
      int realCounter=0;
      int imaginarCounter=0;
      int numberOfElements=6 // this variable is set by the user using scanf, and can be any number>=2. Each komplexNumber consists of two numbers (i.e 9 -3j is a complex number)

       for(i=0;i<numberOfElements*2;i++){ // 
           printf("Enter number %i\n", i+1);
           scanf("%f", &temp); 
           if(i%2==0){  //a complex number consts of two parts. first entered number is first part of number1, second is second part of number1, third is first part of nr 2 etc
               komplexNumbers[realCounter].real=temp;
               realCounter++;
            }
            else{
              komplexNumbers[imaginarCounter].imaginar=temp;
              imaginarCounter++;
              }
//The struct
typedef struct komplexNumber{ 
  float real;
  float imaginar;
} komplexNumber;




//The method that mallocs memory for each element:
void calculation(float a1, float a2, float b1, float b2, komplexNumber komplexNumbers[]){ 

    float temp1 = (a1*a2)-(b1*b2);     
    float temp2 = (a1*b2)+(a2*b1);

    komplexNumber *k;
    k=(komplexNumber*)malloc(sizeof(komplexNumber));              
    k->real=temp1;
    k->imaginar=temp2;
    komplexNumbers[0]=*k;
}

//The loop, in which im calling free each iteration:

int counter=1;
for(i=0;i<(numberOfIterations-1);i++){                   
    a1=komplexNumbers[0].real;
    b1=komplexNumbers[0].imaginar;
    a2=komplexNumbers[counter].real;
    b2=komplexNumbers[counter].imaginar;
    calculation(a1, a2, b1, b2, komplexNumbers);         
    counter++;

    free(komplexNumbers[counter]);
}
```

This program crashes sometimes, and sometimes not. I haven't been able too see a pattern why it does, but it's the `free()` function that causes the crash (since when I remove free and run the program with the same values, it doesn't crash). I have not been able too see a pattern in which causes the crash. It  can handle negative numbers

Note: each struct element is called `complexNumber`, and the array is called `complexNumbers` (with an s:) )

Comment: Show us how you build `komplexNumbers`.

Comment: it's in the "calculation" function

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you're on Linux you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to spot memory-related errors

Comment: Your code is not well formed. You can't have a `for` loop outside a function body. `komplexNumbers` is not declared. Please post a minimal complete compilable example.

Comment: +1 for valgrind - just started using it a few days ago - it is *really* useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a few issues:

- You're always assigning `komplexNumbers[0]` and freeing `komplexNumbers[count]`
- `komplexNumbers[0] = *k` probably means `komplexNumbers` is an array of structs, not an array of pointers - you're assigning a struct, not a pointer

#### EDIT

In light of recent code, it's easier to show you what to do than to explain what you're doing wrong. As suspected, `komplexNumbers` is an array of structs. In your calculation function you don't need all that `malloc` stuff (and consequently you don't need the `free` bit). Do this instead:

```
komplexNumbers->real = temp1;
komplexNumbers->imaginar = temp2;
```

Comment: the value on komplexNumber[0] is saved, and not supposed to be removed. I do a calculation each iteration with komplexNumber[0] and "the next element" and add the answer into komplexNumber[0]

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson So where do you set komplexNumber[1] ? Do you know what the dereference * operator does ?

Comment: I've added some more code showing how komplexNumbers is first built. I was thinking I have some sort of syntax error using the free function, since program does not always crash. if I remove the * in the komplexNumbers[0]=*k declaration, the program does not compile

Comment: ah indeed. I only malloc the first element, the rest is struct members and have no allocated memory on the heap. I'll re-write my program so that I allocate memory for each struct member instead, since im trying to learn dynamic programing in c. I mainly program in JAVA so all this refrence/allocation stuff is making me dizzy :)

Answer (score 1):

Because in calculation you always set value of 0th item (by copying the value pointed by k), then you want to free unallocated array items.

Answer (score 1):

I find this part of code as little messy :-
`komplexNumbers[0]=*k;` inside cacluation . As it will again and again set pointer to complex type only in index 0. When you try and free this While itearting in a for loop using counter it Will fail for values of counter > 0 . I guess so But it would be better 
if you frame question in  a nice way and post so that we can look into it`

Answer (score 1):

How is `komplexNumbers` (the array) allocated? You can not call `free` on anything that has not been returned by `malloc`. And you're leaking memory, the memory for `k` is lost when returning from `calculation`.